# Sealer for inside of bathroom cabinets [thin plywood]

Tags: finishing, plywood

I am creating some floor-to-ceiling stud bay storage in a bathroom. Bathroom is small but has a vent fan.

I am using the RevolutionPly utility sheet goods to line the cabinets. I believe it is made of poplar. It’s pretty thin at 5 mm. I like the striation Of the grain and the slight pinkish cast, which is why I am using it.

I want to seal the wood to protect it from stains from bathroom products that will be stored there. I’ve had several 1/4 sheets in the bathroom for at least six months while in use and have not noticed any substantial problems. There has been some bowing but no delaminating.

I’m not concerned with waterproofing it as much as protecting it from stains. Just wondering what options I have for the finish. I have worked with shellac, lacquer, poly and spar. Mostly I want something that is quick to apply and dry without a lot of residual odor and that will help keep the surface clean/wipeable.

I’m also a bit concerned about the plywood veneer being so thin so I don’t want to use something water-based, according to the manufacturer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. *"Mostly I want something that is quick to apply and dry without a lot of residual odor"* What kind of window do you have for odour to dissipate? Frankly all the finishes you list could work (and different people would choose to use each depending on personal preferences). But as you'll already know real lacquer definitely has an odour, and so does any varnish (including poly). And buttoned up inside any sort of box the smell can linger for a very long time. I happen to not mind this lingering odour, but other people do find it very offputting and it is avoidable.

Comment: If you don't want any odor, water-based poly may be the way to go - if you worry about damage to the veneer, just try it on some offcut. It has no odor (as far as I can tell at least) and it isn't really too "wet", even though it's water based. It may cause no problems at all..

Comment: Thank you for the replies! There are no windows in the bathroom that open. Just a vent fan. It’s a small bathroom. It has a tub shower sink toilet, but basically the size of what most would consider a powder room. I would be finishing the plywood outside and letting it dry and offfgas outside before installing it so I hope that will lessen the chance of an odor.  I’m just not sure how some products linger over time in an enclosed area.  I did try some water-based poly acrylic spray and it actually seem to turn out well. I may apply a second coat to my sample board just to make sure it’s a good

Comment: coating. It seemed a bit thinner than the poly but not as smelly for sure. Thanks again for the replies.

Comment: Can you build the shelving/containers outside of the bathroom, finish them, and then install them to mitigate any odors?